# Scala concatenate Map - one with Option and other without Option

Tags: scala, dictionary, monads

I have the below input values

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.lang.{Double => JDouble}
val date = Timestamp.valueOf("2021-08-01 00:00:00")
 val contractRate: Map[String, JDouble] = Map("ITABUS" -> 0.075,
    "KARAT-S" -> 0.10,
    "KAUTRA" -> 0.05)
  val timeBoundContractRatesList: Map[String, List[(Timestamp, JDouble)]] = Map(
    "ITABUS" -> List((Timestamp.valueOf("2021-07-30 23:59:59"), 0.085.asInstanceOf[JDouble]),
    )
  )
```

My requirement here is:

1. There are 2 types of rates. One is fixed rate and other is time bound rate
2. I need to apply the time bound rate if the date is greater than today (for example)
3. I am trying with the approach to have a single consolidated Map like below

   ```
   val withTimeBoundContractRate = contractRate ++ timeBoundContractRatesList
      .map { case (carrier, timeRateSet) =>
        val filteredEntry = timeRateSet
          .filter { case (startDate, _) => date.after(startDate) }
        (carrier, filteredEntry.map(_._2).headOption)
      }
      .filter(_._2.nonEmpty)
   ```

The problem is with the output. I get the below output

```
withTimeBoundContractRate: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,java.io.Serializable] = Map(ITABUS -> Some(0.085), KARAT-S -> 0.1, KAUTRA -> 0.05)
```

But what I am looking for is a Map with original datatype(without Option)

```
withTimeBoundContractRate: Map[String, JDouble] = Map(ITABUS -> 0.085, KARAT-S -> 0.1, KAUTRA -> 0.05)
```

Or is there a totally different approach to solve this efficiently?

Comment: As I can see, you have filtered nonEmpty values at the end of your map operation, so you can either do: `.map(tuple => (tuple._1, tuple._2.get)) // since you're sure that it is not empty`, or use collect method instead of filtering on nonempty and then using .get method: `.collect { case (startDate, Some(otherValue) => startDate -> otherValue } // uses one iteration instead of 2 iterations.`

Comment: As a rule it is generally better to use Scala types and convert to Java types on the way in/out of Java code rather than using Java types in Scala code.

Comment: You may use `align` from **cats** to merge both maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I think, I misunderstood what you are trying to do originally, so I deleted by first answer, to replace it with this):

You actually almost have it, the only problem is that the values in your second map are `Options`. Just "unwrap" them:

```
contractRate ++ timeBoundContractRatesList.mapValues { 
  _.find(date.after(_._1)).map(_._2)
}.collect { case(k, Some(v)) => k -> v }
```

The main difference from your snippet here is to use `collect` instead of `filter`: it lets you not only remove the empty values, but also transform the non-empty ones to get rid of the `Option` around them.